# ASP.NET C#: How can I call App_code functions inside of web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, global, app-code

This is the code I use in the web.config:

```
<add name="MainRule" virtualUrl="^~/Pages/([\w-_]+).html"
  rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
  destinationUrl="~/page.aspx?pid=${PageTitleToId.ConvertPageTitleToPageId($1)}"
  ignoreCase="true" />
```

In the App_Code folder I have a "PageTitleToId.cs" class which contains the ConvertPageTitleToPageId function which takes a string parameter.

Am I missing something because the ConvertPageTitleToPageId function is not called when I run the page.

Any help is appreciated,

Simplecode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't execute code in your web.config. I would update `page.aspx` to handle a `title` query string parameter on which it calls `ConvertPageTitleToPageId()` to get your `pid`.